# How do you browse games in a PGN file on Linux?

Tags: pgn, database, linux

I've downloaded the database from [ICOfY](http://www.icofy-blog.de/icofy-base/) in PGN format.
Are there any free Linux-based programs that would allow one to browse through it? I mean exploring the game moves tree while displaying position on the board and links to next move alongside statistics?

Answer (score 2):

[Scid vs. PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/) can do all of the above. It will take a while to load since ICOfY Base is rather large (upward of 4 mil games, I believe). Your best bet is probably to convert the PGN file to Scid format using the `pgnscid` command-line utility included with Scid vs. PC. That's what I've done in the past, but if I'm not mistaken, ICOfY Base is now available for download in Scid format.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of free pgn vieweres but the best one is using chessbase

Comment: Is there a ChessBase version for Linux?

Comment: Depends on if you've installed WINE